# How can I tell which routing protocol a wifi mesh network is using?

Tags: routing, wireless

Is there a way to determine it, maybe with some heuristic (sniffing)?

Comment: Could you tell us why it matters?  If you're not participating in the mesh, it should not matter

Comment: Personal interest mostly, but I'm also experimenting with two clients with the same MAC connecting to different points in the mesh.

Comment: Do you mean L3 routing or the L2 routing done by the mesh.

Comment: @fredpbaker the L2 routing done by the mesh.

Comment: I don't think duplicate MAC addresses will work out well, if you had an L3 between them ok, but wireless is just like an Ethernet hub

Comment: it actually does, I tested it, the point of the question is to force the routing protocol to forward packet to one client when the other does not cooperate.

Answer (score -1):

Use Wireshark, to sniff the network.

The Nodes must populate a change in the network if you connect or disconnect a client.

When you catch this intel you can analyse it and **the type of pupulating information across the mesh should gibe you genought information to determine the protokol.**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_protocol_list

the only time i get in touch with a mesh they used OSLR